# Why does the HDMI connection disconnect when setting up with xrandr?

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, awesome

After rebooting I get this in the output of `xrandr`:

```
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98
```

I then try to set it up:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP1
```

At this point nothing happens on the external screen, my main screen just flickers once, and when I run `xrandr` again I get this:

```
HDMI2 disconnected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

If I then restart X or reboot I get back to square one.

In the systemd journal I see a possibly related issue:

> i915 0000:00:02.0: HDMI-A-2: EDID is invalid:

(It's probably worth noting that it does *not* say that the [EDID *checksum* is invalid](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#EDID_checksum_is_invalid))

I've tried [deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml and rebooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Screen_resolution_reverts_back_after_a_blink), but with no luck.

Running Awesome WM on Arch Linux.

Comment: Something to try https://askubuntu.com/q/201081/17531

Comment: The described behavoir sounds similar to [my experiences](https://superuser.com/q/1173207/98286) does get-edid work for you? Which graphics hardware/driver are you using?